# Partitioning or bucketing hive table based on only month/year to optimize queries

Tags: hadoop, hive

I'm building a table that contains about 400k rows of a messaging app's data.
The current table's columns looks something like this:

---

message_id (int)| sender_userid (int)| other_col (string)| other_col2 (int)| create_dt (timestamp)

A lot of queries I would be running in the future will rely on a where clause involving the create_dt column. Since I expect this table to grow, I would like to try and optimize it right now. I'm aware that partitioning is one way, but when I partition it based on create_dt the result is too many partitions since I have every single date spanning back to Nov 2013.

Is there a way to instead partition by a range of dates? How about partition for every 3 months? or even every month? If this is possible - Could I possibly have too many partitions in the future making it inefficient? What are some other possible partition methods?

I've also read about bucketing, but as far as I'm aware that's only useful if you would be doing joins on a column that the bucket is based on. I would most likely be doing joins only on column sender_userid (int).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think this might be a case of premature optimization. I'm not sure what your definition of "too many partitions" is, but we have a similar use case. Our tables are partitioned by date and customer column. We have data that spans back to Mar 2013. This created approximately 160k+ partitions. We also use a filter on date and we haven't seen any performance problems with this schema.

On a side note, Hive is getting better at scaling up to 100s of thousands of partitions and tables.

On another side note, I'm curious as to why you're using Hive in the first place for this. 400k rows is a tiny amount of data and is not really suited for Hive.

Comment: I agree hive is overkill for 400k rows, but that 400k is from less than 5k users and we expect both numbers to grow exponentially. Anyway, that is besides the point since I'm merely asking how it's done.

Also regarding the partition size, I was heeding caution and advice from sources like this: [link](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/08/improving-query-performance-using-partitioning-in-apache-hive/)

"Do not over-partition the data. With too many small partitions, the task of recursively scanning the directories becomes more expensive than a full table scan of the table."

Comment: @tchoedak That is definitely good advice to follow. But, I don't think you partitioning scheme is "over partitioning". By day partitioning is pretty common. You can certainly partition by month or quarter (see answer from @miljanm). However, this puts an unnecessary burden on the users because you need to specify both "month" and "date" to get it to apply the right partition filter.

Answer (score 0):

Check out hive built in UDFs. With the right combination of them you can achieve what you want. Here's an example to partition on every month (produces "YEAR-MONTH" string that you can use as partition column value):

```
select concat(cast(year(to_date(create_dt)) as string),'-',cast(month(to_date(create_dt)) as string))
```

But when partitioning on dates it is usually useful to have multiple levels of the date dimension so in this case you should have two partition columns, first for year and second for month:

```
select year(to_date(create_dt)),month(to_date(create_dt))
```

Keep in mind that timestamps and dates are strings, and that functions like month() or year() return integers as values of date fields. You can use simple mathematical operations to figure out the right partition.